Why does changing coordinates involve weighted sums?
I have noticed that definitions of a contravariant and covariant change of coordinates for a vector often are written as follows.
Contravariant vectors:
$$v^{\beta} = \sum_{\alpha} \frac{\partial x ^{\beta}}{\partial x^{\alpha}} u^{\alpha}$$
Covariant Vectors:
$$v_{\beta} =  \sum_{\alpha} \frac{\partial  x^{\alpha}}{\partial x ^{\beta}}u_{\alpha}$$
Why are they weighted sums? why not just have some arbitrary mapping
$$v^{\beta} = f_{\beta}(u^1,u^2,...,u^K)$$
Why do so many authors assume a weighted sum is needed for a coordinate transformation?

By definition, the tangent space only records the linear information at a point, so anything beyond linear is automatically killed.

You need to pay more attention to the background material. A covector uses a subscript since in a covariant transformation the new coordinates are in the denominator. So you should have written $$v_\beta = \sum_\alpha \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x^\beta} u_\alpha.$$Otherwise you will have ignored the main reason behind the index placement.

@TedBlack ur 100% right lol fixed it

ok now bring down the alpha :-)

@TedBlack Omg how did i not notice that either? LOL wow. good for u man. ill fix it right now

The change-of-coordinates is the map which expresses the $x^\beta$'s in terms of the $x^\alpha$'s. This can indeed be any arbitrary mapping $x^\beta = f_\beta(x^1,\dots,x^k)$.
The way the $v^\beta$'s are expressed in terms of $u^\alpha$'s are the coordinate expressions of the derivative or differential of the $f$ map. And derivatives/differentials are LINEAR maps on tangent/cotangent spaces. Linear maps between any vector spaces, when written in a chosen basis, always appear as "weighted sums" (because they are given by matrix multiplication...in this case the Jacobian matrix of $f$).

It cannot be "any arbitrary mapping." The Jacobian matrix must be non-singular otherwise it is not a valid change of coordinates.

Yes, of course, the mapping $f$ must be differentiable. I was just using the same phrasing that the OP used in their question. But you are right.
